# How to send capital alphabet using keyboard?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Using below code, it sends key in browser URL not in google search text box.
i want to enter text in google search text field using keyboard event in caps.

```
driver.get(https://www.google.co.in/);

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action enterText = builder.click(driver.findElement(By.
                       cssSelector("input[type=text]"))).
                       keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).
                       sendKeys("my gmail").
                       keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).
                       build();
    enterText.perform();
```

Comment: Did you try to use `sendKeys("AABBCC")`? Or is there another reason why you are using these keyDown/Up events?

Comment: Are you using Firefox? Looks like a FF specific issue. I tested Chrome, works fine.

Comment: Yes, i executed code in FF

Comment: If i am not wrong,This is the URL issue not the browser issue.use driver.get("www.google.co.in");This worked in IE too.

Comment: @user1177636 Nope, Its worked perfect for me. I assume you all are coding in java as i do.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code works perfectly for me in FF 21 + Selenium 2.33.0.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7 + Selenium 2.33.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 driver.findelement("YOURELEMENTLOCATOR").sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT,"yourtexttobetyped")
```

Example,

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=text]")).sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT,"stackoverflow")
```

will send you 'STACKOVERFLOW'. or else you can send the CAPITAL letters directly in the send keys as

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=text]")).sendKeys("STACKOVERFLOW")
```

:)

Comment: Yes right, above code will work and even i tried but i want to know why my code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is to uppercase the first letter of password. It worked perfect for me. Kindly suggest to others too.

```
String password = "Done123!";
password = password.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + password.substring(1);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=text]")).sendKeys(password);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple helper function

```
def capitalized(driver, string):
    for char in string:
        if char.isUpper():
            driver.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, char)
        else:
            driver.send_keys(char)
```